Coating a nickel foam with mm poresize with zinc
I'm currently trying to coat a nickel Foam (NF) 1 cm thickness with high loadings and homogenous plating of Zn metal. The main concern right now is that the outer most areas like corners and edges get heavily coated while the inside "bones" are not coated/plated at all.
Until now the technique was electroplating in electrolyte containing: ZnSO4, H3BO3, surfactant and NaCl at 40 °C including a sacrificial Zn-anode.
The current was varied from 0.1A to 0.8A, while the 0.1A showed better results and very low dendrite formation at the high current density areas like the mentioned corners and edges. I also tried heavy stirring, separating the Zn-anode and NF with a glasswool separator, displaying very little effects. Masking these high current density area with paraffin film or similar could be a option but I do not think it would help that much.
Does someone have more experience with this metal foam electroplating and/or has even tried other techniques like electroless Zn plating. The loading needs to be high and homogeneous.

You need to add some details, like what are the concentrations, what is the geometrical surface area of your foam, what loadings do you want, what is the time you're depositing for. The problem you're having sounds very much like either an internal mass transport resistance or ionic resistance. To solve this the simple solution would just be to plate at low current density and/or increase the Zn content and ionic conductivity of your solution.
